# migrating url-loader to webpack 2?

Tags: webpack, webpack-2, urlloader

Using webpack 2, are there any changes that one needs to change in order to configure webpack correctly?

here's what i have for configuration options:

```
modules: {
  rules: [

  {
            test:   /\.(ttf|otf|eot|svg|woff2?)(\?.+)?$/,
            use: 'url',
            query:  {
                limit: 10000
            }
        }
  ]

  }
}
```

i'm currently getting a bunch of errors using this.

error:

`Error: options/query provided without loader (use loader + options) in {`

Answer (score 4):

There are several things you need to change.

- `use` takes an array of loaders. But as a shortcut you can use `loader` to provide just one loader.
- It is no longer allowed to omit the `-loader` suffix. So you need to make it `url-loader`.
- Although `query` exists for compatiblity reasons, it is recommended to change it to `options`.

So your config shoud look like:

```
{
  test:   /\.(ttf|otf|eot|svg|woff2?)(\?.+)?$/,
  loader: 'url-loader',
  options:  {
    limit: 10000
  }
}
```

You should also have a look at the migration guide of the offical docs to see what else you need to change: https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/